# Blob datatype in a mysql table not storing more than 5000 characters

Tags: mysql, scorm2004

I'm working on a quiz which contains large number of questions. It uses scorm 2004 3rd edition. The suspend data limit for Scorm 2004 is 64,000 characters. I use Blob datatype to store this value. But, when the value exceeds 5000 characters it truncates the value to 5000 characters. I cannot store more than 5000 characters. Please help me to solve this. I'm using MyISAM Engine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use medium_blob datatype ;)

Comment: @robert But Blob itself can store around 64 kb right?

Comment: Right, blob is supposed to be 65535 bytes.